# Sublime text 3 and anaconda, python wrong path

Tags: python, path, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

I'm new to python and sublime.
I downloaded anaconda3-5.2, the full version with python3.6, and sublime text 3 on my 64bit machine windows 10.

When i start my sublime text 3 i imediately get the Error:

[image: Problem message box Anaconda]

I really don't know how to solve this. It clearly says it is pointing to a python2.7, and i don't have python this one. I have python 3.6.

On the internet they tell to choose python as builder and as syntax, but this didn't solve the problem.

I also reinstalled anaconda and sublime, but this also didn't fixed it.

Does anybody have a possible solution?

Comment: The message doesn't say that it's running 2.7, it's showing you an example using 2.7. The error says that your configured python interpreter is `python`, so it looks like your problem is that it can't find it. You should try what the message says; either add the Python install location to your PATH or configure Anaconda to know how to find it.

Answer (score 2):

I had got the same issue, but in linux.
I had to change the settings for anaconda in Preferences -> package settings -> anaconda -> settings-default.

Then, I searched for the line related to "python_interpreter" wich default value was python and I changed it to python3. Then I restarted sublime and then it worked fine.

I hope this could be helpfull

[image]

Comment: This worked on Fedora for me.  "python" wasn't in my $PATH but "python3" was.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you installed python 3.6 you most likely you did not check the box to add it to your user PATH environment variable.
Reinstalling and checking the box should fix it.

Otherwise, you could update your user Path Environment Variable adding something like
"C:\Users\OdatNurd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\"